# Button gets extended when using flexbox to

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to put a button at the center of a div section using flex-box.

Here is my code:

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">Button</a>
</div>
```

However, the button is extended after compiling.

How should I modify the codes to avoid problem of extension?

Comment: The div should be the flexbox

Comment: yes you are correct. I just noticed I make a stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: vertical or horizontal or both center ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    .btn{
      padding:0 0;
      margin:auto;
      width:20px;
    }
```

This css will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Button</a>
</div>
```